# Kafka 2.1.1 persistent client DisconnectException

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a Java application that consumes data from a Kafka topic (populated by a different application), using the kafka-clients lib. Usually it works fine but (without changing anything in configuration / deployment) it sometimes gets stuck with the following error:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler handleError [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1914414120, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.

This error usually occurs after loading high volumes of data in the cluster (~500 messages per sec) but it persists for hours even if there is no activity.

The network between the client machine and VM running Kafka seems to be working fine (I can ping, access port with telnet). The Kafka VM has enough CPU, memory and space on disk and other apps running there work fine. Kafka broker log shows no warnings or errors.
I have checked client and server versions to match, for Kafka 2_12 2.1.1

Comment: The client version isn't required to match the server. Try upgrading

Comment: I tried various versions of kafka client : 2.3, 2.8, 3.5 but the issue persists.

Comment: Is the error always mentioning "node 0"? Maybe there's a network problem related to that specific server. Or the thread running "consumer-4"... I'd recommend setting debug/trace logging in your app and try to get more info. Or maybe server logs for "node 0". Also, did you remove the groupId from the log message?

Comment: Yes it is only node 0 because I have a single Kafka server (it's a test environment). I have set the finest log level for client app on org.apache.kafka.clients.*. I have found a workaround for the issue, rebooting the machine running the client app.